# how to dynamically get valuse of gps every time i move my android phone?

Tags: android, service, gps, refresh

in my application i need to update he values when i move my android phone 
so that all the mapping that i am doing gets updated too.
its an augmened reality application
and i need to change the mapping data dynamically that are in service.
please reply if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29). One parameter is minDistance. You can use it to set the minimum distance interval in meters for notifications.

So for example if you set it to 10, then you will get a new location, every time you have moved 10 meters.